Per monitor scaling in Ubuntu 24.04
I would like to select a scale for an external monitor different than the one used in my built-in screen.
Display configuration:

As you can see in the screenshot I only have the option to select a global scale that affects the built-in screen and the external monitor at the same time (or in the same amount if that's more accurate).

Is Kubuntu? It doesn't look like the GNOME settings seem on Ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu Studio 24.04
